What metadata tag should I use for the date/time an analog video was digitized?
When scanning old prints and slides, I use ExifTool to write the MWG:CreateDate tag into the digital files to record when the scans were done. Now I'm having old 8mm home camcorder videotapes digitized, and I'd like to write a digitization timestamp into the metadata for the video files. The QuickTime spec has tags for other image metadata tags I use in my work with prints and slides, but I can't find a tag for representing when the digital version of the video was created. The closest I can find is com.apple.quicktime.creationdate, but that's for when the video was originally recorded, not when it was digitized.
I don't want to rely on file creation or modification dates, because they can change as files are copied around, uploaded and sent, etc.
What is a good way to embed the digitization date into the metadata of a video file? I'm currently using H.264-encoded video in an MP4 container.
Thanks.

MP4 files can hold XMP metadata and there are three tags which correspond to the three main EXIF tags. While technically they are for images, they can be used for videos.
Using exiftool, you could write
XMP:ModifyDate, which would be the last date when the video stream was modified.
XMP:DateTimeOriginal, which would be when the video was actually created.
The date the video was digitized is a bit messy in this case. Originally, the EXIF for XMP standard used the XMP:CreateDate for this purpose. This has been changed recently to  XMP:DateTimeDigitized.
There is the IPTC Video Metadata standard but it does not have an entry for when the video was digitized.
